# How to await an async function evaluation in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

In Puppeteer you can evaluate async functions:

```js
await page.evaluate(async () => {
    // await some promise
});
```

Is there an equivalent in PuppeteerSharp? Using `EvaluateFunctionAsync`, the task completes before the promise resolves:

```cs
await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(@"async () => {
    // await some promise
}");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the right way,
for example:

```
var six = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<int>("async () => await Promise.resolve(6)");
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have done something wrong the first time. I'll give it another go.